# Unable to add window- Android ошибка

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, исключения

```
ISSUE STACK TRACE
view.android.WindowManager$BadTokenException: (Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@2263b2c8 is not valid; is your activity running?)
at view.android.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:556)
at view.android.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
at view.android.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at app.android.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
at app.android.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
at app.android.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3974)
at app.android.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
at app.android.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1299)
at os.android.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at system.dalvik.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

У меня из багтрекера переодически приходит ошибка с таким трейсом. 
Кто нибудь может подсказать в чем может быть проблема? Использую Activity и несколько фрагментов.

Comment: что-то пытается появиться при убитой активности. например диалог